# Flexbox - How to create a responsive dynamic flexbox grid

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to learn and try Flexbox therefore just to build a grid construct that looks like this:

[image]

Possible sizes of boxes: 4x4, 2x1, 1x1 - they are to be dynamic anywhere.

Responsive to all boxes to the same size

Actually i have this :

```css
.tab {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;
  color: green;
}

.col-wrap-4x4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.col-1x1 {
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
.col-1x1.one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.col-1x1.two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.col-1x1.four {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <div class="col-wrap-4x4">
    <div class="col-1x1 four">1</div>
    <div class="col-1x1 two">2</div>
    <div class="col-1x1 one">3</div>
    <div class="col-1x1 one">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything I've tried so far has not worked. 
Does such a thing anyway?

Comment: Ups, sorry ascii image..  Screenshot : http://imgur.com/a/28K3s

Comment: Please don't just post a link to JSFiddle, but add the relevant code here. And don't try to bypass this by disguising the link as source code.

Comment: @cedricreichenbach, he's new to the site. Maybe not totally familiar with the guidelines and code formatting tools. A bit of leniency, perhaps?

Comment: @Michael_B Well, SO prevents you from submitting and displays a big red error message with clear instructions what to do, so it shouldn't be too hard IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

Don't forget that ur parent element must be as big as ur child's + border or margin

```css
.tab {
  width: 604px;
  height: 100px;
  flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;
  display: block;
  color: green;
}

.col-wrap-4x4 {
  width: 230px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.col-1x1 {
  background-color: black;
  /*border: solid 1px green;*/
}
.col-1x1.one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.col-1x1.two {
  width: 110px;
  height: 50px;
}
.col-1x1.four {
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
}
.myClass{
   display: inline-block;
  float: left;
   position: relative;
    margin : 10px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
                                <div class="col-wrap-4x4">
                                    <div class="col-1x1 myClass four">1</div>
                                    <div class="col-1x1 myClass two">2</div>
                                    <div class="col-1x1 myClass one">3</div>
                                    <div class="col-1x1 myClass one">4</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Greetz

Comment: Yep, like this ! 

http://imgur.com/DYUhPii - my dream , without jQuery , possible ?

Comment: yep, like i did it for u, if u use `position:relative`, `display:iline-block` and `float:left //or anything else` it will go automatically to the right position. U have to set Parent `width: ´ dinamic